# Flexbox overflow-x last margin

Tags: html, css, flexbox, margin

I use a translator.
My opinion can not be passed on exactly.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border: 1px solid aqua;
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 400px;
  list-style:none;
  padding-left:0px;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid Aquamarine;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
  <li>item4</li>
</ul>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bLJREL

Unlike what I was trying to do, there is no margin in the last element.

What if you want to add margin after the 'item4' element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `:after` pseudo-element with `width` same as margin to create that space but then you also need to remove `margin-right` from last `li`.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border: 1px solid aqua;
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 400px;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
ul:after {
  content: '';
  flex: 0 0 10px;
}
li {
  border: 1px solid Aquamarine;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
}
li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
  <li>item4</li>
</ul>
```